# Date Field is not working suddenly

Tags: datetime

I had created a field of type Date-ISO Format for a content type. I am creating the content programmatically. Everything was working fine when I was sending a unix timestamp and probably drupal was taking care of it and saving it in the field of DATE(ISO Format) but now all of a sudden it is not working. It either leaves the field blank or saves the current time instead. Can anyone explain this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question with that code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, since it was working fine before and I had not changed anything in it. It was basically getting a JSON object and using the postdata and assigning it to the respective fields. The problem is definitely with the field type.